# Thread overhead

Tags: .net, multithreading

I need some clarification on threads.
When is the 1 MB memory overhead for threads claimed?
Is it when the thread object is created (costructor) or when the Start() method is called?
Does the Start method returns immediately (before the thread really starts)?

If I have a loop that creates and starts N threads > maxThreads of ThreadPool, will the loop complete fast or it will wait till all threads are created and started?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it when the thread object is created (costructor) or when the Start() method is called?

The 1mb (by default, but configurable, as it's the stack size of the thread) is created when the thread actually starts.

> Does the Start method returns immediately (before the thread really starts)?

The `Start()` method is asynchronous, and returns immediately.  [Thread.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.start.aspx)'s documentation specifies that it "causes a thread to be **scheduled** for execution."

> If I have a loop that creates and starts N threads > maxThreads of ThreadPool, will the loop the complete fast or it will wait to be created and started all the threads?

It will complete quickly (or, at least, not wait for the threads to start up).